# UINavigationbar barTintColor not working in UISplitview Template

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

I am trying for hours to change the Navigationbar barTintValue in my App.
I am using the Master-Detail Template from Xcode using Swift and
I read a lots of questions here, but the answer was always to use

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

This works fine in AppDelegate, but I want to change the color in each DetailView depending on its content at runtime.

When i put this code into the Master or DetailViewController just nothing happens. I printed out the colors before and after and it does set the values, it just doesn't change.
Do I need to update the view or something?

Thanks for you help!
Maik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always i just found the answer right after posting this.
I don't think its the solution, but its a workaround.

I change the color for the detailView in prepareForSegue, and change it back to default in the masterViews viewWillAppear.

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem.
I have found a solution.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: This only change the navigation bar color not status bar color