# is it possible to apply two navigation colors for two view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i have situation where i need to have blue color as  navigation bar color for first view and for second view i should have as green color .when i tried to apply it using below code.

in viewdidload for 1st view:
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor bluecolor];

in view did load in second view:
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

the color remains same as in first view i was unable to change it,and how to remove glassy effect on navigation bar.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/26256149/643383 answer your question? Also, it's not clear what you mean by *glassy effect*, but UINavigationBar has a `translucent` property that you can set to `NO`.

Comment: Try to put your code in the viewDidAppear

Comment: i have place in viewdidappear but result is same .i was unable to change color

Answer (score 0):

Select your navigation controller in your view hierarchy(in Storyboard), select the navigation bar and from there you can set the color in the attributes inspector.

Comment: I don't doubt that this might work, but OP seems to be looking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: i have changed top bar  in navigation bar to opaque but how to change color of navigation bar in story board

Comment: @user3816512 What do you mean?